# Breeze WebApi and Breeze Angular Working Sample

Tags: breeze

I am really struggling to find a working example of a Breeze WebApi and Breeze Angular applications working together.  Heck, I can't even find examples of them working on their own.

I've downloaded the Breeze-Samples package, but the Todo-Angular app is missing a bunch of files and won't build.

I've got a decent understanding of how Breeze works once it's setup, but I can't get any working examples.  I just want to see what's under the hood for initializations, API calls, etc.

Any recommendations for good examples here?

Comment: All of the.NET samples use Nuget to download libraries.  Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try John Papa's Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1 & 2 on [Pluralsite](http://www.pluralsight.com/)

While you are there you can also checkout Brian Noyes's [Building Data-Centric Single Page Apps with Breeze](http://www.pluralsight.com/)

Plus many, many more tutorials on both subjects.